# Submit button with anchor tag

Tags: html, forms

I have a contact form with two submit buttons (the buttons both have the same function, apart from one is higher up the page)

Both buttons have validation on them (if a checkbox is not ticked a warning pops up)

IF the submit button that is higher up the page is clicked and the validation not complete, I would like the page to jump to the bottom.

I have tried wrapping the input button with an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#seccta">t<input type="image" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/108/c/5/Green_Submit_Button_by_rukiaxichigo15.jpg" onclick="if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('Please read and agree to the terms and conditions first.');return false}"  /></a>
```

and put the anchor code at the bottom of the document:

```
<a name="seccta"> </a>
```

... but it doesn't work. It works when I put text in place, but a submit button breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I added another onclick to the anchor and that has solved my problem:

```
location.href='#seccta'; if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('Please read and agree to the terms and conditions first.');return false};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wraping the button, put it before or after the button

```
<a href="#seccta">t</a><input type="image" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/108/c/5/Green_Submit_Button_by_rukiaxichigo15.jpg" onclick="if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('Please read and agree to the terms and conditions first.');return false}"  />
```

For the user, it wont make any change, since you will be pointing righ after/before the button. If you need to put a blank character use

```
<a href="#seccta">&nbsp;</a>
```

Try it

Comment: I just put the "t" in the example to show that it worked with text.
I want the page to jump to the bottom if the warning pops up.